# How does TLS securely negotiate a shared secret?

Tags: ssl

I understand how a TLS connection can be secure once the shared secret can be used to encrypt the request/response, but how does TLS create the initial secure shared secret without being susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that there is some authentication to make sure that one is talking to the right party (typically done with certificates) and once one can be sure that it is the right peer the key exchange is done (typically Diffie Hellman). This whole handshake process is also protected against manipulation.

For the finer details please see [How does SSL/TLS work?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20803/how-does-ssl-tls-work).